# Error on terminal open: -bash: /nvm.sh: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, terminal, nvm

Every time I open my terminal the first line says: `-bash: /nvm.sh: No such file or directory`.

I just installed nvm on this laptop and obviously I did something wrong.

Does anyone know what commands I can use to fix this?

I tried the following command to remove nvm from my laptop:
`$ rm -rf ~/.nvm`

Sadly, this did not fix my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your .bashrc file (usually in the home folder). See answers to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/49289/what-is-the-bashrc-file). There's probably a line reading `/nvm.sh` somewhere in there -- if so, just delete it.

Answer (score 2):

As Gasper Stukelj awnsered:
There was a line reading `/nvm.sh`.
The correct path to the file was for me using macOS Mojave:
`$ open ~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 2):

In my case I fixed this problem, just putting in terminal, after installing nvm: `export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"` and `[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"`
and after that I installed node normally

**How did I find this solution?**
Simple, I read the terminal, and it gave two ways to solve. The first option was for me to restart the computer, to see if the changes (installation) took effect, and the second option was for me to put these two commands in the terminal and only : )
Ready to use in my case :)

*I used Google Translate*

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was coming from the .bash_profile file. The line was:

```
source ~/.nvm/nvm.shexport PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.0/bin:$PATH"
```

I removed everything after nvm.she and the error isn't showing in the terminal anymore. This happened while trying to install xdebug on Mac Big Sur.

Answer (score -1):

I failed to find a solution in Google searches, so I just installed `nvm` again to resolve the issue. I guess some files were not installed.

```
brew install nvm
```